# how to run the same chef recipe multiple times with different parameters

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

I have a recipe that installs a process on the filesystem , and then a runit service to manage the process - which finally notifies a command to copy the unique configuration to the process home directory and restart the process. This works fine for a single process - but when I try to run this multiple times ie. when looping over attributes, I get weird side effects that appear to be lifecycle related.

An example of an error I get

```
Chef::Exceptions::EnclosingDirectoryDoesNotExist
```

for /srv/second-process. However this directory is the first one I create in the notifying block inside the provider - could it be the chef runs aren't isolated ? I have also seen data from the first array item leak into the other ie. first-process attempting to notify r_unit[second-process-id]

In broad terms, (if only a single process this works)

```
node["app"]["processes"].each do |key,value| 

    #step 3
    execute 'configure' do  

         command 'cp -r /srv/folder /srv/#{some_key} && sv restart #{some_key}'
         action :nothing

    end
    #step 2
    runit_service current_process_id do

      notifies :run, 'execute[configure]', :delayed

    end
    #step 1
    my_custom_hwrp current_process_id do

      notifying_block do

         new_resource.dirs_to_create.each do |dir_name|

         end

         install_path current_install_path
         notifies :enable,"runit_service[#{current_process_id}]"
      end
    end

end
```

my_custom_hwrp  provider

```
class Provider < Chef::Provider
   def action_enable 
      deploy_revision current_process_id do 

          new_resource.updated_by_last_action(true)
      end
   end
end
```

Is there a way I can isolate the chef run for each process?

Comment: Try with `execute "configure #{some_key}" do  ` to get unique execute command for each directory, and use the same syntax in the notiication. Without that each resource overwrite the previous one (short explanation, it's a little more complicated). I had use `remote_directory` and notification to restart the service instead of `execute`.

Comment: you should implement a [definition](http://docs.chef.io/definitions.html) or a [lwrp](https://docs.chef.io/lwrp.html), which you will be able to reuse even across cookbooks. you can always invoke either of which iteratively.

Answer (score 0):

The way that Chef works you end up with one resource `execute[configure]` which will be based on the last `key` `value`.

If you are creating resources using a loop, make sure that all resources have unique name.

For example

```
execute "configure-#{key}-#{value}"
```

Otherwise results will be unpredictable.